# Endless Video Recording

Tags: android, video

I am building an app that will hold a 60 second buffer of recorded video. The video recording needs to run for an extended period of time (24-48 hours). I do not seem to have any issues with recording, but it appears that I lose the connection with my `Camera` or `Surface` after a few hours of time.

I am setting the max duration: `MediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10 * 1000)` so that recording is broken up into 10 second segments.

Each time I restart my recording I am incrementing the output file in such a way that 6 files are reused. The purpose is to keep a 60 second history at all times.

If I stop the recording after 1-2 hours the videos play back fine. However, if I let it run for 3-4+ hours and stop the recording, the videos shows only black output **with** audio. In other words, it is as if it lost a connection with the camera or surface **but continued recording audio**.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

If nothing else, is there a better way to record **X** second segments of video?

FYI: I am using a wake lock so that the screen/CPU stay on.

Comment: I've never tried anything like that. But if you can get 1-2 hours in without problem quick dirty fix seems like finish() and restart your recording Activity. But that is going to leave you a gap in recorded video that is the size of your activity startup time. If you have 2 devices you could record from both and alternate restart times?

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. In reality I believe that I could be doing something out of order with the recording operations. As in, it might *normally* be able to reconnect to the camera, but there could be that 1% case where it gets ahead of itself (MediaRecorder isn't finished writing/closing output file when I try to start recording again?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sort of answered my own question here. I don't have a lot of information, but hopefully this will provide enough information to help others in a similar predicament.

First, I never posted my code because it's *way* too lengthy. I didn't post snippets of my code because I did not know where the problem was originating. Despite the fact that I have this working now, I still do not know what was wrong with my old code.

**My suggestion:**

I ended up scrapping my code and starting fresh with the code found in the Development API Demos: [`CameraPreview`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html) -- I found this references in at least one thread on this site.

After that I was able to continually record for hours on end without problem. So if you are in a similar situation, I would suggest using the `CameraPreview` code as a starting point.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to do something similar but with smaller lengths (record last 15-30 seconds of video+audio) but i am having a hard time making it work. Can you tell me which is your minimum API level your project is?

Also, if you can provide more information about this it would be great, like if you are using some other external libraries, which objects/methods you are using, how are you merging the resulting videos (or if it is done automatically).

Thanks